# Import error when importing types in SvelteKit typescript app

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

When trying to run my SvelteKit app I get the following error:

`error: Expected "from" but found "{"`

`import type { ProductsListType } from '../types';`

I have a types.ts file where I export my typescript types:

```js
export type ProductType = { name: string; link: string; imgURL: string; alt: string };
```

And in my index.svelte I import the type:

```js
<script context="module" lang="typescript">
    import type { ProductType } from '../types';
</script>
```

This error appeared from one day to another. I tried to revert my package updates but the error remained.

Comment: I face the same problem. Did you find any solution to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: @Labaguette the `lang` attribute in the script tag needs to be _ts_ not _typescript_ so `lang="ts"`